# Фильтрация файлов из папки в bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс, glob

Вообщем есть такая проблема, мне нужно из папки вытаскивать названия файлов по определённой маске, но так как я не силён в регулярных выражения пробовал делать так:

```
<?php foreach (glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/client_files/" . $gui . "*.xls") as $filename):
    echo "Filename " . $filename . "\n\r";
endforeach; ?>
```

Файлы хранятся вот в таком виде: a96ca0cd_Документ.xls
Но тот код который я использую не работает мне бы еще на 2 расширения файла сделать xls и xlsx.

Comment: то есть, "маски" это расширения файлов?

Comment: @InDevX Нет не только расширения файлов у каждого файла в начале определённый набор символов guid по нему и нужно отбирать файлы и конечно же по расширению

Comment: Можно, к примеру (тем кто регулярки не любит, не знает и т.п..), разбивать сперва имена по разделителю `$items = explode("_", $filename);` брать первый эл-т и сравнивать его с нужным паттерном `$items[0] = 'blabla'`, расширения проверять можно аналогичным образом, только разбивать по точке и брать последний эл-т `$items[count($items) - 1]`

Comment: @InDevX С одной стороны это действительно проще, но не повлияет ли это отрицательно на скорость т.е. мне кажется одна регулярка будет работать быстрее чем несколько explode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем-то я нашел ответ на свой вопрос(решил забить на расширения поскольку задача изменилась) и теперь делаю так:

```
preg_match('/' . (int)$guid['guid'] . '\_[а-яА-Я\w]+/', $entry)
```

Как говорится слава онлайн генераторам регулярных выражений.